# I have tried gdal builidng from source and rpm and still get the following error trying to create the postgis extension

Tags: postgis, postgresql

create extension postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.5/lib/rtpostgis-2.2.so": /lib64/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: atom_obj_cache

Comment: As a relatively new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Be sure to also review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/framing-asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1):

finally removed the gdal-libs.rpm and postgis2_95 rpm installed gdal and postgis from source
low and behold it works  so there must be an error in the rpm's